# Does compact set always contain supremum and infimum without Heine Borel?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

On this post:

[compact set always contains its supremum and infimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553905/compact-set-always-contains-its-supremum-and-infimum)

People ask if compact set always contains its supremum and infimum. I know that it is true on $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.

> Pf: Let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a nonempty compact set. Suppose not, by Heine Borel $K$ is closed, so the $\sup(K)$ lies
>   in the open set. Take an open ball around the $\sup(K)$, then $\sup(K)
>  -\epsilon$ is the new supremum, contradiction.

However, this requires Heine Borel. And in that post, people are basically saying, that since compactness = closed and bounded, the above proof always works, so compact set always contains supremum and infimum.

Does a compact set in general topological space necessarily contain sup and inf?

Comment: What do you mean by "sup and inf" in a general topological space?

Comment: Might want to restrict your question to the order topology.

Comment: @Hayden  Most order topologies (other than those similar to $\mathbb R$) don't have many interesting compact sets though. The whole concept seems pretty useless outside of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @mathguy Oh, I don't know. The order topologies of well-ordered sets (ordinals) have compact sets which I think are kind of interesting.

Comment: Let $X$ be3 a topological space, and let $\lt$ be a linear ordering of $X.$ If $\{x\in X:x\lt a\}$ is open for every $a\in X,$ then every compact nonempty subset of $X$ has a greatest element. Likewise, if $\{x\in X:x\gt a\}$ is open for every $a\in X,$ then every compact nonempty subset of $X$ has a least element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general topological space there is no order relation - and therefore no meaningful definition of sup and inf.

Comment: Really better as a comment.

Comment: I initially posted it as a comment, but then I thought this is in fact "the" answer - pointing out that the question really doesn't make sense. What other answer is possible; that is, what WOULD constitute an answer rather than a comment?